# Find the matrix of the transformation conjugate to $f(x, y) = (x - y, 2x)$ in the basis $(\mathbb R^2)^*$ conjugate to the basis $\{(1,1), (1, 2) )\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Find the matrix of the transformation conjugate to $f(x, y) = (x - y, 2x)$ in the basis $(\mathbb R^2)^*$ conjugate to the basis $\{(1, 1), (1, 2) )\}$ of the space $\mathbb R^2$.

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand the conjugate transformation. From what I understand, the conjugate transformation matrix is the transposition of the transformation matrix $f$. Then that would mean that it is the matrix tracing in standard bases, so I compute it:
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x-y \\ 2x \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow M(f)_{st}^{st}=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$
However, I am given a non-standard basis to find the conjugate basis to, so I think I should find the matrix $M(f)_{st}^B$ and its transpose will be the conjugate transformation matrix I am looking for.

But I don't know how to calculate $M(f)_{st}^B$ and if my reasoning is at least correct.

**Edit using Anne Bauval hint:**

For $B=\{(1, 1), (1, 2) )\}$:
$$\begin{cases}f(1,1)=(0,2)=a(1,1)+c(1,2) \\ f(1,2)=(-1,4)=b(1,1)+d(1,2) \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}a=-2\\ c=2\\ b=-4\\d=3 \end{cases} \Rightarrow M(f)_B^B=\begin{bmatrix} -2 & -4 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$
So the matrix of the transformation conjugate is: $$A=\left( M(f)_B^B \right)^T= \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 \\ -4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$
Is it correct?

Comment: Your $(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,1,2)$ is false and anyway useless. Compute directly the 2 columns of $M(f)_B^B$ (not $M(f)_{st}^B$) For instance the first column will be $a,c$ such that $f(1,1)=a(1,1)+c(1,2).$

Comment: @AnneBauval I edited my question about your hint, it is correct?

Comment: $f(1,2)=(-1,2),$ not $(-1,4)$ but your $b,d$ and your conclusion are correct. Your previous $M(f)_{st}^{st}$ has not been corrected.